# What triggered the movement from the late archaic to the early classical/severe era?

Tags: ancient-history, art, greek, classical-greece

Most art historians say the movement resulted from the Persian Wars. I've also read that the rejection of Persian ideals and culture triggered the movement into the classical style art. Does anyone have any sources they could share that could possibly provide insight to this question?

Comment: Asking for sources or references is off topic. Also, the question involves highly subjective theories, not historical facts, so it is not a good fit for this site which has as its focus non-subjective history. Unfortunately, there is no art history stack exchange, so I do not know where you could go to discuss this, maybe an art history forum on the web like http://www.wetcanvas.com ?